# How to stop Google Analytics Hacks?

Tags: google-analytics

What people are doing is basically taking the UA-XXXXXX code that you normally get with analytics, and they are generating calls against it. This is skewing my analytics stats. On top of that, in Google WebMaster tools, it's also causing this:

[image: People hacking my analytics stats]

It looks like somehow these pages, with my code on or at least with the generated code on, is making Google Webmaster tools think I have lots of 404's. This can't possibly be good for my rankings.

Anyone know if there is anything you can do to stop this?

Comment: Is this related to: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-referrer-spammers/75914#75914 ??

Comment: I will see if I can get Google's attention again.

Comment: To prevent this from skewing your analytics stats, see this:  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56713/could-somebody-hijack-my-google-analytics-for-a-site